# Get select element value on event using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, html-select

I want to get the value of a select element when the select element is clicked! I want to do it without an `onchange` attribute in the HTML.

I would like to achieve this without jQuery. I don't want to include a jQuery framework into this website when this tiny script is the only thing I need.

```
var select_element = document.getElementById('product-form-user-enquiry-type');

select_element.onchange = function(e){
    if (!e)
        var e = window.event;
    var svalue = select_element.value;
    alert( svalue );
}
if ( select_element.captureEvents ){
    select_element.captureEvents(Event.CHANGE);
}
```

The `select_element.value;` contains an empty string. How should I do this?

Comment: actually this seems to work for me
type sth in the textfield on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vW9g/) an click enter

Comment: If you do not want to use `onchange` then don't use `onchange`. Add a `click` event listener to your `select` element.

Comment: i thought about that too, but maybe he just don't wants to include onchange in the html tag itself,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution that will work with all browsers (including IE8) :

```
var select_element = document.getElementById('product-form-user-enquiry-type');

select_element.onchange = function() {
    var elem = (typeof this.selectedIndex === "undefined" ? window.event.srcElement : this);
    var value = elem.value || elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
}​
```

Comment: window.event.srcElement is now deprecated.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement

Answer (score 13):

```
​document.getElementById('test').onchange = function() {
    alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].val​​​ue);
};​
```

Does the above the work?

Edit:

Edited to reflect your select id's etc.

```
var select_element = document.getElementById('product-form-user-enquiry-type');

select_element.onchange = function(e){
    if (!e)
        var e = window.event;
    var svalue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    alert( svalue );
}​
```

See it working at: http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/4WUsG/

Answer (score 1):

`.onchange = function() { ... }` seems to overwrite other handlers, so I use [addEventListener("change", function() { ... })](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)