# Link for Dropdown

Tags: javascript, select, load, selectedindex

I want to select index of a combo with link.
I tried this:

```
<script>
    eval(document.location.hash.substring(1));

    function poke(num, zat) {
        var selObj = document.getElementById('okey');
        selObj.selectedIndex = num - 1;
        var selObj = document.getElementById('nope');
        selObj.selectedIndex = zat - 1;
    }
</script>

<select id="okey">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
    <option>five</option>
</select>

<select id="nope">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
    <option>five</option>
</select>

<button onclick="eval(document.location.hash.substring(1));">okey</button>
```

Button is working fine, but when i tried to load page, it show errors.

Error is like that: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of null` 
How can i do? The code is same. But load is not working, button is working. Huh?

Comment: Why are you evaluating code in "onclick" handler?

Comment: Because, I want to be sure about the code is working. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how you can achive that by evaluating code :)

Comment: I found it, thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no selectedIndex attribute. You can set the selected option by setting the

```
selected
```

attribute on the option element

Comment: Of course there is a `selectedIndex` – it was defined in DOM Level 1 already, see http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement

Comment: take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683934/get-select-element-value-on-event-using-pure-javascript) it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found it!
Now, my code is like that:

```
<body onload="eval(document.location.hash.substring(1));">
<script>
function poke(num, zat) {
var selObj = document.getElementById('okey');
    selObj.selectedIndex = num - 1;
var selObj = document.getElementById('nope');
    selObj.selectedIndex = zat - 1;
}
</script>
<select id="okey">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
<option>four</option>
<option>five</option>
</select>
<select id="nope">
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
<option>four</option>
<option>five</option>
</select>
```

Thanks to everyone who wants to help me! :)