# Get the value of a selected option in a dropdown select menu

Tags: javascript, html

If I have this html snippet and want to store the selected value as a variable in a js file, would it be possible?

```html
 <select>
       <option value="a">Not good</option>
       <option value="b">Alright</option>
       <option value="c" selected>Pretty good</option>
       <option value="d">Excellent!</option>
    </select>
```

I'm trying to avoid using jQuery as much as possible too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get select element value on event using pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683934/get-select-element-value-on-event-using-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You just do this:

```
var selectVal = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;
```

Then `selectVal` is the `value` of the selected `<option>` in the `<select>`.

Comment: So does [0] automatically get the selected option? Or just the first one? The option value that's selected is automatically the "Pretty good" one but if a user were to change it I'd want to know what they chose instead. Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: @vtq This is getting the value of the `<select>`. The value of a `<select>` is the same as the value of the selected option.

Comment: @vtq `[0]` isn't indexing an option, it's indexing in the `NodeList` that `getElementsByTagName()` returns.

Comment: @vtq That's just getting the `<select>` element - you don't have an ID, so you can't select it any other way

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! I wasn't sure if it was just returning an array of all of the values. I'm trying to teach myself JS by doing challenge problems I find online.

Comment: You could also use `document.querySelector("select")`

Comment: @vtq It would be best to give it an ID, in case you have multiple menus. This just gets the value of the first menu on the page.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I wish I could but the challenge problem is trying to teach me how to be more comfortable with JS and the DOM structure so I gotta do it without an ID but I will definitely make IDs for everything that I create lol. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var select_element = document.getElementById('select');

select_element.onchange = function() {
    var elem = (typeof this.selectedIndex === "undefined" ? window.event.srcElement : this);
    var value = elem.value || elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
   <option value="a">Not good</option>
   <option value="b">Alright</option>
   <option value="c" selected>Pretty good</option>
   <option value="d">Excellent!</option>
</select>
<div id="value"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get value of current selected option, you can use:

```
var menu = document.getElementById("select_menu_id");

var selected_option = menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].value;
```

To get text of current selected option, you can use:

```
var selected_option = menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].text;
```